# Any object referencing datarow automatically updating after Rows.Add() operation?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my webpage i implemented a functionality to add/update worksheet task detail information from popup to repeater on page level and it will be saved to database on final save click. User can add/update new task detail through popup to repeater. So i managing user information in viewstate datatable each and every time i retrieving and updating viewstate. My question is when user edit any particular row then i want to store that datarow only so lets suppose if i have two rows in repeater already then i iterate through data table then i have if...else block to check matched record if i found matched record i updating user entered information to grid and same time i storing this datarow to either object or datarow but when in next iteration it executed Rows.Add operation for the rest of the rows at that time it also updating my variable records. Every time it returns two rows whereas it should retrieve only single row that stored inside object even viewstate failed in this case. I dont know about this behavior of dotnet kindly let me know whether i am wrong in my logic or what could be the reason foe this behavior?

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow dr, drEditedRow;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hfIndex.Value))
        hfIndex.Value = "0";
    if (Convert.ToInt32(hfIndex.Value) == i)
    {
        dr = dtedit.NewRow();
        dr["iSrNo"] = dt.Rows[i]["iSrNo"];
        dr["WorkSheet_Id"] = dt.Rows[i]["WorkSheet_Id"];
        dr["Work On Date"] = txtWork_On_Date.Text.Trim();
        dr["WorkSheet_Detail_Id"] = dt.Rows[i]["WorkSheet_Detail_Id"];
        dr["Description"] = txtWorkSheet_Desc.Text.Trim();
        -----

        dtedit.Rows.Add(dr);

       DataRow drEditedRow = dr; // Here i stored edited row to datarow object
    }
    else
    {
        dr = dtedit.NewRow();
        dr["iSrNo"] = dt.Rows[i]["iSrNo"];
        dr["WorkSheet_Id"] = dt.Rows[i]["WorkSheet_Id"];
        dr["Work On Date"] = dt.Rows[i]["Work On Date"];
        dr["WorkSheet_Detail_Id"] = dt.Rows[i]["WorkSheet_Detail_Id"];
        dr["Description"] = dt.Rows[i]["Description"];
        -----

        dtedit.Rows.Add(dr); //
    }
}

// here i using drEditedRow for Linq query
// it should return single row that i have stored in drEditedRow but instead it returns 
// all the rows in datatable because when i debug
// i found it automatic updating records after each Else block dtedit.Rows.Add(dr) execution
```

> Hope its clear now

Comment: It is really hard to guess the code out of your descriptions. Can you give us the code of "iterate through data table"?